# convert array got as string from "file_get_contents()" back to array

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

When I try to get data from an API using

```
file_get_contents("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDINR%22)&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=");
```

I got the result as a string. Is there any way to convert it back to array? 
The string which I got is

```
string(202) "{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2014-03-11T13:00:31Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"rate":{"id":"USDINR","Name":"USD to INR","Rate":"60.99","Date":"3/11/2014","Time":"9:00am","Ask":"61.00","Bid":"60.98"}}}}"{"error":"","msg":""}
```

please help me....

Comment: Yes. http://php.net/json_decode (Set the second parameter as `TRUE` to get an array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your request, you ask that the returned format be `JSON`-encoded (via the `format=json` parameter), so you can just decode the response into an array using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode):

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDINR%22)&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=");
$response = json_decode($response, true);

// Parse the array as you would any other
```

Comment: thank u fro the fast rply... :)

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it proved useful :)

Comment: need to have 15 reputation for accept it.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON answer here so jo need to dekode that.

```
<?php
$s =  file_get_contents("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDINR%22)&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=");$data = 
$data = json_decode($s,true);
?>
```

and the $data variable will be an array.